# Sortable custom column in ActiveAdmin index view : joins, group and count hell

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-activerecord, activeadmin

We're using ActiveAdmin for our admin view, here's the current index code. The Book model retrieves data from a single "books" postgres table :

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :stories, class_name: "BookStory"
```

...

```
 ActiveAdmin.register Book do

  index do
    column :id
    column :title
    column :subtitle
    column :isbn_13
    default_actions
  end
...
```

I would like to add a "stories" column in our index view. A "story" is an action from an user, associated with a book. The stories are stored in a "book_stories" table.

```
class BookStory < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user,
  belongs_to :book,
```

From a SQL point of view, this is how I would like to implement the query into ActiveAdmin. This query gives me the wanted result into pgAdmin3 :

```
SELECT books.id,books.title,books.subtitle,books.isbn_13,COUNT(book_stories.book_id) AS count
FROM books 
INNER JOIN book_stories ON books.id = book_stories.book_id
GROUP BY books.id
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 30;
```

And I really don't know how to implement a **sortable** "Stories" column into our admin view. By sortable, I mean, being able to sort the book like by their stories count. I managed to show the stories count per book with this code, but the column isn't sortable :

```
 ActiveAdmin.register Book do

  index do
    column :id
    column :title
    column :subtitle
    column :isbn_13
    column :stories do |book|
    BookStory.joins(:book).group.where("books.id = #{book.id}").count
    default_actions
  end
...
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on the `belongs_to` `counter_cache` option. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#counter-cache

```
class BookStory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book, counter_cache: true
end

ActiveAdmin.register Book do
  index do
    column :id
    column :title
    column :subtitle
    column :isbn_13
    column :book_stories_count # will be sortable by default
    default_actions
  end
end
```

Comment: Okay, so far I've updated my database using a rake db:migrate task

class AddBookStoriesColumn < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_table :books do |t|
      t.integer :book_stories_count, :default => 0
      end
    end
  end

Now the column :book_stories_count is here but filled with zeroes. Still looking how to populate the column with the proper values. Thanks :

Comment: You need to do something like this `Post.find_each { |post| Post.reset_counters(post.id, :comments) }`